# Compare 2 columns and highlight new items in second column

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, compare

Situation:
I have an excel macro which imports a column of data into an existing sheet in the next free column, it also clears formatting of the previous column which will be set at the completion of the macro (the bit I'm trying to work out here).

I need the code to compare each cell in the new column to the previous column to see if there is a match, if no match then highlight the cell.

Problem:
I keep getting type mismatch errors, or the code does not run. My latest attempt (which incluces copying the unique data to a different sheet which would be a bonus if working) is below.

```
Dim rngCell As Range

For Each rngCell In Range(Cells(2, Worksheets("Data").Columns(LastColumn)), Cells(10000, Worksheets("Data").Columns(LastColumn)))
 'I know hardcoding values is bad, but i did this for testing purposes
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(2, Worksheets("Data").Columns(LastColumn)), Cells(10000, Worksheets("Data").Columns(LastColumn))), rngCell) = 0 Then
        Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = rngCell
    End If
Next
```

Ideal outcome:
The code runs through and highlights unique values in column 1 (using column index references as each day a new column is imported).
The code copies the unique values to another sheet for ease of use.

Thanks in advance for any pointers or code.

Comment: Please clarify your requirements - to me it's not clear what you want to achieve: highlight new items, copy unique values ... If this is clear, it is easier to help you.

Comment: The title of your question does not match with what you explain in the question text and the code you show. Please, better explain what you want accomplishing and what do you think your code should do.

Comment: Where in your included code are you copying to a different sheet? I think it would be easiest to include a picture of some example data and what the result is supposed to look like. Yo usay you want ot highlight in the second column, but then you say column 1. And there is no formatting being set in the code as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only posting a part of your code, I'd have to assume that the part wher you insert and clear formatting is already working well.
Sometimes you define a worksheet, sometimes you don't so I'm not sure what sheet we are working with here.

But just to clarify, if you had data in column "A", and then ran the macro to paste data in column "B", would you want something like this:

```
prevCol = 1
lastCol = 2
Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, prevCol), Cells(100, prevCol))
Set Rng2 = Range(Cells(2, lastCol), Cells(100, lastCol))
For Each rngCell In Rng
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng2, rngCell) = 0 Then
        rngCell.Interior.Color = RGB(250, 230, 20)
    End If
Next
```

[image]

Where unique items in the column that existed before the new one got inserted are highligted?

So in the end, maybe something more like this:

```
Sub SubName()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long
Set sht = Worksheets("Data") 'or whatever
' Instert column
' clear formatting

lastCol = sht.Cells(2, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, lastCol - 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each rngCell In Range(Cells(2, lastCol - 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol - 1))
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(2, lastCol), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)), rngCell) = 0 Then
        rngCell.Interior.Color = RGB(250, 230, 20)
    End If
Next
End Sub
```